# Incorporate a text file into the build of my app

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I want to incorporate a text file into the "Build" of my program for the iPhone.  Other then copying and pasting into the code, how can I do this?  I have many data files that I would like to include in the build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `NSString` method `stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:` to read the contents of any file in your project into an `NSString`.

Include the file in your project (no copy and paste required). Simply right click on the list of files, select `Add`, select `Existing files`, and navigate to the file to include.

Then, in the code where you want to load the file, use

```
NSString *txtFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myTxtFile" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *txtFileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:txtFilePath encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
```

However, if you want to have more structure, then you should use a `plist` to store an `NSDictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a .txt file to your application bundle. Please explain more what actually you want to do?

Comment: For example:  Each text has a names and phone number for each state.  I want to load this into the program when building it so I can access the data when I run the application.  I do Not want to use the database.  thx

Comment: You can get data from text file. Using some file operations. But I think you should use plist file it will be easier and better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use plists to provide prepared data lists in your app.  You can read them in with the NSArray function `arrayWithContentsOfFile:` or the NSDictionary function `dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:`.